# Correct way to address wrong grammar in ANTLR

Tags: antlr4

I use ANTLR to parse a programming language. According to the ANTLR book (chapter 9.4) i implemented some "Error Alternatives". An easy implementation is described in the book by notifying the error listener:

```
.....
| ID '{' expr '}' '}' {notifyErrorListeners("Too many braces");}
.....
```

After reading the book i thought it would be easier to implement the notifications as listeners so i wrote in my BaseListener:

```
public void exitExprError(@NotNull MyParser.ExprErrorContext ctx) {

        parser.notifyErrorListeners(ctx.start, "Too many braces", null);

}
```

In my listener i can extract the start and stop token from the context which gives me a finer grained control where to mark the error (ctx.start).

However the listener in the grammar file is simplier and faster to implement as the listener.

My question is:

Is it also possible to add arguments to the listener in the grammar file?

Something like:

```
.....
    | ID '{' expr '}' '}' {notifyErrorListeners(ctx.start,"Too many braces");}
.....
```

Comment: [Sure](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.java#L551). You could also add your own overload.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But I think i will use now listeners which gives me more flexibility.